# Pivot Not working

Tags: sql-server

Here's my input data:

```
model                            status_description Number
NULL                               ASSIGNED           1
CABLE CARD                         ASSIGNED           56
DCT1000                            ASSIGNED           1130
DCT1200                            ASSIGNED           134
DCT2000 Digital                    ASSIGNED           21401
DCT700 Digital                     ASSIGNED           22214
DCX3400 HD Digital Rec.            ASSIGNED           1183
DCX700 HD Digital              ASSIGNED           1086
CABLE CARD                     CHARGE/DISCONNECT      2
DCT1000                            CHARGE/DISCONNECT      43
```

And on and on with those same Models and ultimately 9 Statuses.

I want to present the data as so...with the Models down the left side and the 9 Statuses across the top with the numbers for each. My query presents the data in the right format but all the counts are coming up NULL. My query is down below. Any thoughts as to why?

```
Model         ASSIGNED  CHARGE/DISCONNECT DELETED HOLD  OFF ISLAND OUT OF CIRCULATION   
5 Port eMTA     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
6381-DSL Modem  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Pivot SQL:

```
select Model, 'ASSIGNED' = [1], 'CHARGE/DISCONNECT' = [2], 'DELETED' = [3], 'HOLD' = [4], 'OFF ISLAND' = [5], 'OUT OF CIRCULATION' = [6], 
'PENDING' = [7], 'RETURNED/REJECTED BY CUSTOMER' = [8], 'UNASSIGNED' = [9]
from (select model, status_description, number from jed_convert_031314) as PivotInput
PIVOT
(SUM(number)
for status_description in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9])) as PivotOutput
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would go with Dynamic SQL statement:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(status_description) 
                    from jed_convert_031314
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Model,' + @cols + '
             from 
             (
                SELECT *
                from jed_convert_031314
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                SUM(Number)
                for status_description in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6732e/19)

Comment: Awesome and perfect! You have been a great help to me.